# 'int' object is not subscriptable while comparing with a list

Tags: python

I am very new to python, so please excuse if I ask this basic question.

I created two functions:

- `in_range()` checks whether a value is within a range
- `calculate_temp` should compare a given value with a list of ranges and assign a point value as result

```
def in_range (lowerlimit, upperlimit, value):
    if lowerlimit <= value <= upperlimit:
        result == True

    else:
        result = False

    return(result)

temperature_ranges = ([1,4,11],[5,10,22],[11,20,33],[21,52,123])

def calculate_temp (temperature):
    for temperature_range in temperature_ranges:
        val = 0
        if in_range(temperature_range[val][0], temperature_range[val][1], temperature) == True:
             points = int(temperature_range[val][2])
        val +=1

     return(points)
```

However `print(calculate_temp(3))` prints out the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.
```

Although as far as I can see all elements are integers.

Comment: Please include the **full** traceback, not just the line that calls your function.

Comment: Either `temperature_range` is an integer, or `temperature_range[val]` is, so the next `[..]` subscription is applied to an integer.

Comment: As an aside, your `in_range` function should simply be `return lowerlimit <= value <= upperlimit`

Comment: Also, `result == True` is not an assignment, that's an equality test.

Comment: You can just return the result of the `lowerlimit <= value <= upperlimit` test. That *already* produces `True` or `False`. `return lowerlimit <= value <= upperlimit` is all you need in the `in_range()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Temperature ranges has is a list of lists. When you iterate over it in

```
for temperature_range in temperature_ranges:
```

you get a list for each iteration named temperature range, lets say [5, 8, 12]

```
print(temperature_range[val])
#5
```

finds the first element in that list, which is an int

Then you try to find the first element of that int:

```
temperature_range[val][0]
```

Which is equivalent to

```
5[0]
```

Which is clearly nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

A few points (mainly a list of all the people that commented before me):

1. `temperature_range` is in the form of [int, int, int], it is not a `([int, int, int], [int, int, int], [int, int, int])`, so you don't need `[val]`.
2. When you `return(result)` in the `calculate_temp()` function, result is not defined, I assume you meant `points`.
3. `result == True` is a comparison, not an assignment.

Check this code, it worked for me:

```
def in_range (lowerlimit, upperlimit, value):
    if lowerlimit <= value <= upperlimit:
        result = True

    else:
        result = False

    return(result)

temperature_ranges = ([1,4,11],[5,10,22],[11,20,33],[21,52,123])

def calculate_temp (temperature):
    for temperature_range in temperature_ranges:
        val = 0 # this variable is not used anymore...
        if in_range(temperature_range[0], temperature_range[1], temperature):
            points = int(temperature_range[2])
        val += 1 # no need to keep it if you dont want
    return(points)

print(calculate_temp(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is crashing because `temperature_range` is already a sublist from the global `temperature_ranges` list. You do not need to take an element of the global list as you do with `temperature_range[val]`. If you wanted to do it this way, then you should be taking a value of `temperature_ranges` and not `temperature_range` (notice ending **s**). For example, you could do:

```
def calculate_temp (temperature):
    for val in range(len(temperature_ranges)):
        if in_range(temperature_ranges[val][0], temperature_ranges[val][1], temperature):
            points = int(temperature_ranges[val][2])
    return(points)
```

Further, your code can be significantly simplified as follows:

```
In [114]: def in_range (lowerlimit, upperlimit, value):
     ...:     return lowerlimit <= value <= upperlimit
     ...: 
     ...: temperature_ranges = ([1,4,11],[5,10,22],[11,20,33],[21,52,123])
     ...: 
     ...: def calculate_temp (temperature):
     ...:     for temperature_range in temperature_ranges:
     ...:         if in_range(temperature_range[0], temperature_range[1], temperature):
     ...:             return int(temperature_range[2])
     ...: 

In [115]: calculate_temp(3)
Out[115]: 11
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The simplification really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. That really helped.

```
if in_range(temperature_range[0], temperature_range[1], temperature):
        points = int(temperature_range[2])
```

Fixed the problem. Thanks!